# Await function returning undefined response object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

I am not much experienced with async/await, but I have incorporated the keywords in a function which basically fetch or POST data to MongoDB database. It seems like **await** does not wait for the **promise** to be fulfilled and returns an **undefined** response object.

I am getting the following error:

res.error(404).json({message: e.message})
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'error')
at Object.getAllItems (/Users/myName/Desktop/TODOList/backend/Controllers/ItemsConroller.js:12:13)

Here is my code:

ItemsController.js:

```
const getAllItems = async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const items =  await Item.find({})
        res.status(200).json(items)
    }
    catch(e){
        res.error(404).json({message: e.message})
    }
    
}
```

Server.js file:

```
app.get('/todos', (req, res) => {
     dbItem.getAllItems().then(data => {
         console.log("entered")
         res.send(data);
     })

})
```

Same problem with other functions in the controller file which incorporates await/async keywords.

Thanks.

Comment: That's not what the error message says at all. It says that `res` is `undefined`. Given that you call `dbItem.getAllItems()` and don't supply any parameters, it shouldn't be surprising that the second one is `undefined`.

Comment: My bad. I see it now. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing your req and res object to your `/todos` endpoint:
To make you app more robust try this:

You can use `getAllItems` as your middleware like this

```
app.get('/todos', dbItem.getAllItems, (req, res) => {
     if(!req.error){
         res.send(req.items)
     }else{
       res.send(req.error)
     }
})
```

And attach your variables to the req object and pass them to `/todos`

```
const getAllItems = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const items =  await Item.find({})
        req.items = items
        next()
    }
    catch(e){
        req.error = e.message
        next()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This sure helps clarify more. Thank you :)